# Amazon s3 upload 1tb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

im uploading 4tb from my linux server to my amazon s3 bucket, I made a test with files like 5mb and it was succesfull so I know that it is working. Then I configure a crontab to make the upload of a directory of 4tb during the night but it doesnt show up on the bucket the next day, I think that it is because of the 4tb.

Have someone make a test like this one of uploading BIG directories?

The crontab is configured with the sync command. 
[Also in the bucket appears files that I dont know what they are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MgdT.png)

[Example of one of them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eukmp.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [s3 file access denied for large files using cyberduck](https://superuser.com/q/1027060/52365)

Comment: Your "example of one of them" in not in fact an example of one of them.  That's an error message telling you that you are not allowed to see the file in question.  Use the "Download As" button above the list of objects to actually download a file.

Comment: How are you doing the upload? What error message (or otherwise) do you receive?

Comment: I´m using the sync command in the crontab to run every day at 3am: 0 3 * * * s3cmd -r sync /root/to/directory/ s3://bucket